# SpaCy General Questions

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am new to the community and to using any NLP packages. Currently I'm using SpaCy to get semantic similarity of two docs, I'm trying to understand this process.

1. Does SpaCy use a custom tokenizer?
2. Are the token vectors created by SpaCy/Explosion and just loaded through the model en_core_web_lg for instance. If the vectors already exist within the model what is the purpose of the tok2vec function? Is it to create new vectors?
3. Are all parts of SpaCy (tokenizer, lemmatizer, POS, NER, etc.) trained using the same corpus (OntoNotes 5. Clear NLP, etc)?

If someone can explain how the process works and how does it do it (is it trained to behave that way or not) I would really appreciate it!

Have read their website but they do not offer much information for beginners.